# Шифрование данных в локальной БД. Robospice

Tags: java, android, шифрование, orm, криптография

Нужно решить задачу безопасного хранения данных в локальной БД. Использую библиотеку Robospice.

Хелпер:

```
 DatabaseHelper extends RoboSpiceDatabaseHelper
```

Не понятно, можно ли не изменяя суперкласс добавить шифрование.

Или можно просто добавить либу и использовать

`net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;` 
вместо `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 основных подхода к шифрованию БД:

1. Шифруется целиком вся БД (в случае SQLite - это файл БД)
2. Шифруются только отдельные поля, как правило BLOB поля

SQLCipher - шифрует всю базу целиком. То есть если вы будете его использовать, то достучаться до БД стандартными средствами будет невозможно.

Если же хотите пойти по второму пути, то вам всего то навсего нужно научиться читать и писать шифрованный/дешифрованный поток байтов в виде наследника `InputStream/OutputStream`, через который и организуется чтение/запись в BLOB поле.